# how to hide series data in combination high charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using combine `high charts`. I need to hide a particular pie chart and column chart data while clicking a particular legend. If i use:

```js
series[i].data[index].remove()
```

That removes the value but not able to show that value again while clicking the legend.

```js
series[i].data[index].hide()
```

Refer to this [JSFidddle - Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j6kab0g3/100/)  which I tried but I get an `error` like **This  is not function**. How do I solve this?

Comment: The pie have only on serie so you can delete the `for` loop and use `this.series.hide();` . Now the pie will hide. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/j6kab0g3/110/)

Comment: i need to hide column also.

Comment: Hi SANJAY V, do you also need to hide `line` series points?

Comment: No,  Just hide pie chart and column chart based on legend

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hide` method on point SVG graphic element:

```
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(e) {
        var index = this.index;
        var chart = this.series.chart;
        var series = chart.series;
        var len = series.length - 1;

        if (this.visible) {
          series[0].points[index].graphic.hide();
        } else {
          series[0].points[index].graphic.show();
        }
      }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d8uaxefo/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

Comment: Thanks , but i tried your changes , i need to hide opens and clicks values also(Black and green) for particular legend. http://jsfiddle.net/cbs1zokn/3/

Comment: PPOTACZEK , Thanks a lot for yours guideness, That's working

Comment: Here is an example how to hide all `column` series points in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/an82p5qw/

Comment: Hi, Need one more help, if i remove the particular column value while clicking legend, no need space ,so other column values need to merge.

Comment: Any solution for this case. And how to upload my screenshot for your refernece?.

Comment: Hi SANJAY V, I think that the best will be if you create a separate topic with a detailed description for this issue.