# how to hide series data and categories in combination high charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use combine highcharts. i need to hide categories value also.
I need to hide a particular pie chart and column chart data and categories value while clicking a particular legend.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/an82p5qw/

Comment: Why do you ask the [same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473941/how-to-hide-series-data-in-combination-high-charts) ?

Comment: yeah same, but i need to hide categories  also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `breaks` from `broken-axis` module to hide the part of axis with data.

```
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function() {
                    var value1,
                        value2;

                    if (this.index) {
                        value1 = this.index === 1 ? 0.5 : 1;
                        value2 = 0.5;
                    } else {
                        value1 = 0.5;
                        value2 = 1;
                    }

                    if (!this.visible) {
                        breaks[this.index] = {}
                        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].update({
                            breaks: breaks
                        });
                    } else {
                        breaks[this.index] = {
                            from: this.index - value1,
                            to: this.index + value2,
                            breakSize: 0
                        }
                        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].update({
                            breaks: breaks
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tgrs3o0d/

Comment: I try the above things,but that's not working for my case. i think may be some javascript files make error. which js files we need to use. refer below links  http://jsfiddle.net/tgrs3o0d/2/

Comment: Hi SANJAY V, You forgot to add the code that was in `load` event:
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dq0mrej4/

Comment: i need text alignment like this  SUMMARY <space>  ADDRESS. the legend values(SENT,OPEN,CLICK,OPENRATIO) come under the SUMMARY. other values(1@gmail.com,...) come under the ADDRESS. http://jsfiddle.net/dq0mrej4/2/

Comment: Or Summary<space> Sent open click open ratio.  Address <space> 1@gmail.com 2@gmail.com ...

Comment: hi, any suggestions.

Comment: Hi San in FC, You can set right legend width and hard space `&nbsp;` to align legend items in two columns. But to arrange them correctly in groups, you would have to change `layoutItem` method in Highcharts core. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aohn1zv8/